# With password, how to find the passphrase for a full disk encryption after a clone

Tags: xubuntu, encryption

1. I first installed Xubuntu 18.04 with full disk encryption with the
   default option; I remember the password, but lost the passphrase
   accidently.
2. I cloned my original disk with clonezilla to a new disk;

Now I want to recover the passphrase for the new disk, and would like to know if it is possible?

Comment: No! it's not...

Comment: If you know parts or the structure of the passphrase or you have a weak passphrase, you can try `JtR` with `luks2john`. If not, the data is lost.

Comment: this is why encryption is like playing with fire. people need to stop looking at it like a fun toy. it should be hidden in the ubuntu install options. 99% of end-users don't need it and a lot of new users end up with these sorts of problems.

Comment: @tatsu no, encryption is **very** important to avoid data loss. But people **need** to start doing backups of important data. Unless you do backups, you ***WILL*** loose data - with or without encryption.

Comment: fair enough. I just think so many problems arise for new users out of os-level encryption that simply can't happen when you haven't ticked that option durring install. people see that option there and think "oh cool, a neat trick that's completely hands-off and encapsulated" ...it's not hands off. you have to know what you're doing.

Comment: @tstsu Thanks for your comment. I haven't lost data since I can log into the system with my password. I want the passphrase to see some files when the disk is used as an external hard disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical answer whether this is possible is: NO, it's not possible.

And this is by design. This situation being easily solvable would defeat the purpose of encrypting itself.

Think of it this way  : it isn't much of a safety net, if anyone can circumvent it.

Captain Hindsight would like to add that in the future you should make sure to keep the password and the passphrase in several places if memory cannot be trusted (and it probably shouldn't). Also backups backups backups! Always make backups!

Comment: Please, use proper formatting of capital letters. BTW, I appreciate your answer.